# Jenkins plugin to monitor custom metrics

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, static-code-analysis

I have a build-system where one of the tools in the toolchain is analyzing the code and performing static code analysis. The metrics are outputted in an xml-file similair to the one below:

```
<metrics>
  <metric name="metric_a">65</metric>
  <metric name="metric_a">32</metric>
  <metric name="metric_a">42</metric>
</metrics>
```

What I want to in Jenkins is to be able to parse this file and then be able to visualize the metrics over time as well as set thresholds so build should fail if for example `metric_a` is below a certain value.

I've been looking for a suitable plugin but the closest I've found is the [Warnings Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin). However the Warnings Plugin parses logs and aggregates the results by utself rather than parsing an actual file with the final metrics.

Are there any other plugins suitable for handling "custom-metrics" or what is by best option?

Answer (score 0):

1. For visualization, you could go for the [Measurment Plots Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Measurement+Plots+Plugin).
2. For failing the build when falling below thresholding on a custom metric, I can only think of making the metric's name/format identical to some existing plugins, e.g. Findbugs or PMD and configure those plugins accordingly.